# The cd command in C and use of chdir()

Tags: c, linux, cd

I'm tasked with programming the linux `cd` command in C. I thought this would be fairly trivial by using the `chdir()` method, but my directories aren't changing. What's interesting is that the return status of chdir() is 0, not -1, meaning chdir() has not failed. Here are the two cases where I'm using `chdir()`:

1.

```
    char *dir = getenv("HOME");   // Here dir equals the home environment.
    int ret = chdir(dir);

    printf("chdir returned %d.\n", ret);
```

`ret` returns 1.

2.

```
    int ret = chdir(dir);   // Here dir equals the user's input.

    printf("chdir returned %d.\n", ret);
```

`ret` returns 1 if the directory exists in my path.

Am I using `chdir()` wrong? I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine that "your directories aren't changing"?

Comment: Are you expecting it to change the directory of the shell you're in? If so, searching the web will help you out.

Comment: How do you check that the cwd isn't changed? You realize that `chdir()` "only" changes the cwd for the process that calls it?

Comment: You cannot write `cd` as an external utility. If you are writing a whole shell, you must avoid `fork()`ing first

Comment: @thatotherguy *technically* you can ... *if* the moved shell is aware of that (which is probably none): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94365/23529

Comment: @Swordfish wouldn't the process that calls `chdir()` be the process that changes to the specified directory?

Comment: Each process has its own current working directory. The shell is a process, your program is a process. When your program calls `chdir()` that changes the cwd of your program, but not the cwd of the shell.

Comment: @DanielJour that's a good question. My program is essentially an infinite loop that asks for the user's input. if they write `cd`, I just use CTRL + C to exit the program and check if my directory was changed. Is this an incorrect way to check? Shouldn't the directory just be changed?

Comment: @poppinMartinellis please read my previous comment.

Comment: `CTRL + C` means you exit your program (which is the process which changed working directory) and "return" to the shell process (which *didn't* change working directory)

Comment: @Swordfish Ah I see! That's good to know, thanks a bunch. If the goal is to change the directory of the user (based on input in a program), how can we avoid changing the process' directory and instead change the shell's directory?

Comment: *I'm tasked with programming the linux cd command in C.* – Are you sure you understood correctly what's asked of you? Could it be that you're asked to implement a simple shell that has the ability to change its own working direktory and show that to the user with a prompt?

Comment: @DanielJour Gotcha, Swordfish just informed me about the difference between the shell's process and the program's process. That makes more sense as to why nothing is changing lol

Comment: have a look at [`getcwd()`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html)

Comment: @Swordfish That would make more sense. I am asked to implement a shell, but the ladder part of your question was not specified. If the program's process' directory is changed, I think that would really be all that can be done. Also, thanks for the tip on `getccwd()`, I'm using that already and can see how I can solve this by using that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`chdir()` changes the working directory of the calling process only.**

So when you have code like ...

```
int main() {
  // 1
  chdir("/"); // error handling omitted for clarity
  // 2
}
```

... and compile that to a program `example` and then run it in a shell:

```
$ pwd # 3
/home/sweet
$ ./example # 4
$ pwd # 5
/home/sweet
```

Then you have two processes in play,

1. the shell, which is where you entered `pwd` and `./example`
2. `./example`, the process launched (by the shell) with your compile program.

`chdir()` is part of your compiled program, not the shell, thus it affects only the process with your program, **not** the shell.

So, at `// 1` the working directory of your program (in above example run) is `/home/sweet`, but at `// 2` it is `/` as specified in the `chdir()` call above.  This doesn't affect the shell and the output of `pwd # 5` though!

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for spelling this out. @Swordfish helped me realize that I was confused on processes.